# MIPS Shift Amount Bit Number

Tags: mips

If a computer's register size is 64 bits, how many bits can I shift?

I assume that it must be 63 but I'm not sure.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tagged your question [mips] and mention 64-bit registers, so I assume that you're talking about MIPS64.

In which case you've got at least 3 different possibilities depending on which instruction you use:

- `DSLL`: 0-31 bits
- `DSLL32`: 32-63 bits
- `DSLLV`: 0-63 bits

---

See *MIPS® Architecture For Programmers Volume II-A: The MIPS64® Instruction
Set Reference Manual* for more details.